# Is there a difference between tomatoes got red and brown and tomatoes got red and got brown?

Tags: difference

Is there a difference between tomatoes got red and brown and tomatoes got red and got brown, and if so, what is the difference?

Comment: "tomatoe" is not a word.

Comment: Neither makes much sense. Tomatoes _turn red_ when they are ripe (except for yellow varieties!), and if one turned brown it would have gone bad and be unfit to eat. If something turned red _and_ brown, it would show both colours at once.

Comment: I would not use **got** like this; it's not completely *wrong*, but it sounds "foreign" and non-fluent.  More fluent would be to say they *turned red* or *became red*.